# How to handle OAuth2 redirect on the frontend side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0, axios

I am trying to implement a OAuth2 flow for a for a Single Page Webapp, but I don't know how to handle the Frontend/ Javascript redirects side.

I have the backend figured out: I'm using a library that does all the work and exposes 2 routes:

- `/auth/authorize` returns a json response like this:

  ```
   { "authorization_url": "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d263f54&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx&state=eyJ0eXAiOiJkdjsfkj&scope=read" }
  ```
- `/auth/callback` that when called back as the `redirect_uri` by the OAuth provider (Github here), either returns a json response like

  ```
   {"access_token":"jhfgkjhdfkjghkdhgkdhgfd","token_type":"bearer"}
  ```

  (if Bearer authentication is used), or simply `null` (if Cookie authentication is used. In that case the cookie is correcly set on the browser)

How should I handle this on the frontend though?

Whe a user clicks the Login button, I can redirect them to Oauth provider login page with something like

```
window.open(axios.get('/auth/authorize').data.authorization_url);
```

, no problem.

But then, if in my OAuth provider I register the callback to be `/auth/callback`, the user will be redirected to a page that only shows text, which is not good.

I think I am supposed to register a Frontend route as the OAuth provider callback, and that route should listen to the response from the OAuth provider, and manually forward the *exact* same response to the backend's `auth/callback`.

How do you do this in Axios/Javascript?

Is there a correct/best practice way to do this?

Thanks!

(as additional infos, the backend library I'm using is FastAPI-Users and frontend is in Vuejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've always done it is to make the redirect URI the base path of the app, then process the OAuth response when the app loads. Here is some [example React code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.tsx#L43) of mine that does this.

I combine this with [pre and post login code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts#L54), which deals with removing login response URLs from the browser history and restoring state, such as the original apication path. so that deep linking works.

**MULTI TAB BROWSING**

The above technique of a `handlePageLoad` method is also useful for setting  up the authentication state, if the user opens a new browser tab or reloads the page. So I think it works better to run it from any path, rather than to use a specific route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It'll definitely take a while to digest all that, but very useful